# Facebook android sdk 4.9 can't open share dialog

Tags: facebook-android-sdk, android-facebook, facebook-share

I have developed an app using facebook android sdk 4.9 and I am in the testing phase. All was well until I tested the app on a Samsung tab running android 4.0.3 (API 15).

I have followed the exact [guide](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/android), but it shows a dialog which says

"Unable to show the provided content via web or installed version of  Facebook app. Some dialogs are only supported starting API 14"

Again, if the device has the latest Facebook app, its works. But my guess is it should work for all devices on and above API 14 with/without Facebook app. Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: facing same problem